# Installing Linux on the TI-nspire

Tags: linux, system-installation, arm, calculator

I am having trouble installing Linux on my TI-nspire cx cas graphing calculator.

I downloaded the files and the Linux image. I have read several websites on the topic but it was not that much help, please tell me how you installed Linux on your TI-nspire calculator.

Here are some websites that I used

http://hackaday.com/2012/11/12/linux-on-a-nspire-cas-cx-calculator/
http://hackspire.unsads.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page

Answer (score 2):

You first need Ndless- Do you have it? If not, Google how to install it.
Second, launch the LinuxLoader. Now load the INITRD and the KERNEL with the commands. After that, use BOOT

Source:
I did it myself on a TI Nspire CX.

Comment: Do you know if I went and bought one of these calculators that this would still work, or has Texas Instruments patched it?